# the sum of two Linked Lists

Tags: java

A class Nat represents a Number (n) by having pre field which points to the n-1 number, if pre is null it means the number is zero.

```
public class Nat { 

     private final Nat pre; 
     public Nat (Nat pre) { this.pre = pre; } 
     public Nat () { this(null); } 
     public boolean isZero () { return pre == null; } 
     public Nat succ () { return new Nat(this); } 

     … 
    }
```

and I have to add a method which adds two numbers, I dont understand how this suppose to return a Nat which represents the sum of "this" and other!

```
public Nat plus (Nat other) { 

 if (other.isZero()) 
 return this; 

 return succ().plus(other.pre); 
}
```

I think it creates a "Nats" which point to the second Nat of this (pre) all the time..
Could any one help me please?

Comment: what is `succ` supposed to do? Where do you store the "number" that the `Nat` is representing?

Comment: @Fildor  { return new Nat(this); }, as I said, by having a pre field (also Nat) which points to the n-1 number (it's so liked the LinkedList behavior just imagine that this represents a number by counting how much Links you have!)

Comment: Ok, so it is supposed to return the successor... Then in your "plus" method, why do you use `succ` and `other.pre` - doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Fildor , I didn't do this, doesn't make sense to me aswell, that's why i'm asking!

Comment: Ah, no - I see. You are supposed to return the correct item out of the list, of course.

Comment: @Fildor, btw, how you see that it returns the successor? I guess it does not, It just creates a new Nat which points to the successor, which means it creates another copy of "this" Nat!

Comment: No, it creates a new Instance, that has "this" as predecessor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if `this` represents `n` and `other` represents `m`, to calculate `n` + `m` is equivant to calculating `n+1` + `m-1`, which is exactly what `succ().plus(other.pre)` returns.

At the end of the recurssion, the first number reaches `n+m` and the second number reaches `0`. That's why you return `this` when `other.isZero()` is true.

Comment: In 'return succ().plus(other.pre);' how can it access 'other.pre' if 'pre' is declared private?

Comment: @Mina it's all within the same ```Nat``` class

Comment: @Mateusz Dymczyk It's accessing the other Nat private field not its own

Comment: @Mina It doesn't matter. From within the same class, you can access any private members of any instance of that class. Without this capability it would be hard to implement methods such as clone and copy constructor.

Comment: Well, I always implemented those using getters for such fields: No need for the hard way anymore for me!

Answer (score 1):

You don't store the numbers directly in the list and create it recursively:

1. [null] -> 0
2. [null -> Nat1(pre=null)] -> 1
3. [null -> Nat1(pre=null) -> Nat2(pre=Nat1)] -> 2
4. etc

**Why the plus() works:**

Now we can observe that addition `x+y` can be changed to `(x-1)+(y+1)` etc. until `0 + (y + x)`. In your code you are not really interested in addition per se but you want to get to the `Nat` which represents the result of the summation. You do that recursively by using the above transformation until `other` is `0` - this is your base case which simply counts the recursive calls and makes sure you do them `x` times.

**Example:**

```
[null -> Nat1(pre=null) -> Nat2(pre=Nat1) -> Nat3(pre=Nat2) -> Nat4(pre=Nat3) -> Nat5(pre=Nat5)]
```

And let's say you want to add `3` and `2`. First you start with `other=Nat2` and call it on `Nat3`, so you get `Nat3's` successor which is `Nat4` and call `plus()` on it using `other's` predecessor which is `Nat1`, still no zero so you call `plus()` on `Nat4's` successor (`Nat5`) with `Nat1's` predecessor which is `null`, you hit your base case and return `this` which at this point of recursion is `Nat5`.

Answer (score 1):

- It is similar to tail recursion

Basically it unrolls the equation

```
n + k = (n + 1) + (k - 1)
```

Until k is zero. In the process a lot of temporary Nats are created but the final result is the Nat where the other Nat addend is zero: you kind of accumulates the result in the first Nat. Write down a simple execution of the algorithm with all the calls and you will see it.

Example: 1 + 2

```
1.plus(2)
-- 1.succ().plus(1)
---- 1.succ().succ().plus(0)
------> 1.succ().succ() == 3
```

EDIT: contrary to the other posts, I think this is **not** strictly speaking a recursive recursion. In fact the plus() method is not called always on the same object instance. The behavior is indeed recursive though. Then it depends on your definitions

Comment: could you elaborate on your definition of recursion?

Comment: Sure: it is more about the def of a recursive method though, not recursion in general. I'd say that a method is recursive if it calls itself at some point. With "itself" I mean also on the same object instance. If you come from a functional programming background though, this won't make sense to you, because it looks like the same function called on a different object instance reference/pointer, thus it calls itself. Anyway, this is splitting the hair a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

This recursion is easier to understand in a **functional language**.

I am sure that other posts are clear enough for `plus` (`a+b` becomes `a+1+b-1`).

What it has to be clear is related to this part:

```
 public Nat (Nat pre) { this.pre = pre; } 
 ...
 public Nat succ () { return new Nat(this); }
```

When `succ()` is called, it returns a new Object, so `this` from here:

```
 public Nat succ () { return new Nat(this); }
```

will be `pre` from here:

```
 public Nat (Nat pre) { this.pre = pre; }
```

This is why that `succ` works because there will be something like `this.pre.pre....pre` at the end.

To understand better, you can type this (eventually add some print lines in your methods):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("==== A new number is 0 ====");
    Nat n1 = new Nat();                 // 0 
    System.out.println(n1.isZero());    // true
    Nat n2 = new Nat();                 // 0
    System.out.println(n2.isZero());    // true
    Nat sum = n1.plus(n2);              // 0
    System.out.println(sum.isZero());   // true
    System.out.println(n2.isZero());    // true
    System.out.println("==== Test succ and pre ====");
    Nat one = n1.succ();                // 1
    System.out.println(one.isZero());   // false
    Nat two = one.plus(one);            // 1 + 1
    System.out.println(two.isZero());   // false
    System.out.println(two.pre.isZero());       // false
    System.out.println(two.pre.pre.isZero());   // true
}
```